# Move a popup after databinding

Tags: silverlight, popup

I would like to display a popup above my control when the user 'mouse over', problem is that the contents of the popup is a ListBox that databinds so I do not know the size of the control (to set the margins), I  have tried every event listed in intellisense on the popup but the ActualHeight of the popup is zero (want to subtract from Margin.Top), any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For this, I would recommend using a ToolTip.  This way you can format the tool tip to show with a list box that is data bound.  For example: A normal tooltip would look like:

```
<sdk:Label Content="{Binding SomeBinding}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip Content="Some tool tip." Name="ttSomeToolTip"></ToolTip>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        </sdk:Label>
```

What I assume you're doing is this:

```
<sdk:Label Content="{Binding SomeToolTip}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip  Name="ttSomeToolTip">
                                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyListBoxSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedListBoxItem,Mode=TwoWay}">                                            
                                    </ListBox>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        </sdk:Label>
```

I can't guarantee that this proposed solution will work, but you have one of two options: Target the LayoutUpdated event for the ToolTip and do a render transform matrix to resize the tool tip container.  Theoretically, the tool tip should resize automatically.  So if you're not already using the above mentioned approach, try that and see what happens.

Comment: I never thought about using a tooltip, nice idea, will test and let you know. I would like for the tooltip to display directly above my control, and idea how I could do that?

Comment: Well, I never tried to do that, but the first thing I would do is get the default XAML template for your control, then modify the "tooltip" portion to use the same position as your control. But i think it's relative....normally you have to adjust the placement property of a tool tip, and they only give you - Bottom, Left, Mouse, Right and Top.  So to get it completely over the control. From the sound of it, you are trying to do a dropdown button...I would just template a combobox to look like a button, and keep it's pressed state on an open, by setting the click mode to hover.

Answer (score 0):

You must run code via Dispatcher, then your code runs in UI thread and you have access to control size.
See [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/185158.aspx)